# How do you check if a string contains an int at a specific location?

Tags: c#, regex, string, isinteger

I want to make sure that a folder has the correct name format before proceeding. The code below demonstrates what I am trying to do, although {char.IsDigit} doesn't work. I would like to replace char.IsDigit with something that means "any digit".

```
if(versionName == $"Release {char.IsDigit}.{char.IsDigit}.{char.IsDigit}.{char.IsDigit}")
{
    //Do something
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8) with a regex like:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(versionName, @"^Release \d\.\d\.\d\.\d$"))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Note `\d` just matches a single digit, if there can be more than 1 digits

```
@"^Release \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$"
```

And tightening it all up:

```
@"^Release \d+(?:\.\d+){3}$"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ERelease%20%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%7B3%7D%24&i=Release%201.12.123.1234) and [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5ERelease%20%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%7B3%7D%24):

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't when I wrote that message as it said I had to wait 5 minutes